# ng-View not working in Single Page App

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-view

I am working on getting an Angular SPA working for the first time. And running into some issues. I can't seem to get the `ng-view` to render or route correctly. Doesn't seem to be able to either parse the `ng-view`.

File Structure

[image]

mainController.js

```
var propManApp = angular.module('propManApp', ['ngRoute']);

propManApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl : '../public/main.html',
    controller  : 'mainController'
})

.when('/about', {
    templateUrl : '../public/about.html',
    controller  : 'aboutController'
})

.when('#/contactUs', {
    templateUrl : '../public/contactUs.html',
    controller  : 'contactUsController'
})

.otherwise({redirectTo : 'index.html'});
});



propManApp.controller('mainController',['$scope', '$log',
function($scope, $log){
$scope.message = "Message Here!!!!!!";
}]);

propManApp.controller('aboutController',['$scope', '$log',
function($scope, $log){
$scope.aboutMessage = "About Message Here!!!!!!";
console.$log("Test");
}]);


propManApp.controller('contactUsController',['$scope', '$log',
function($scope, $log){
$scope.contactMessage = "Contact Message Here!!!!!!";
}]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head ng-app="propManApp">
    <title>Rental Properties</title>
 <!-- angular/  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Logo -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-        toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Rental PROPERTIES</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Menu Items -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

main.html

```
<h1>{{message}}</h1> Main
```

about.html

```
<h1>{{aboutMessage}}</h1> About
```

Browser Inspector:

[image]

Comment: Did you read error message? It clearly explains what your problem is.

Comment: Try to move `ng-app` from the `head` tag to the `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the ng-app tag to head and not html tag. That means your app revolves around only head tag and it does not include the body tag in which the ng-view is used.

So in your index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="propManApp">
<head >
    <title>Rental Properties</title>
 <!-- angular/  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
```

Change it like this.

Also You haven't included mainController.js. Include it in index.html after jquery file.

Comment: Changed it to the HTML and same issues.  Not sure if I am loading the ng-route correctly.  From what I have seen I am but this is my first Angular app.

Comment: Crap. I totally missed it. You haven't included mainController.js.
Include it in index.html after jquery file

Comment: Edited my answer as well

Comment: You can set the Ng-app on the head tag. You can set it on any tag you want as long as you just use the app in the nested tags.

Comment: I thought if you were using ng-view you didn't need the controller in the Index.html. Since you have the route in the controller, and referenced via the ng-app. Again please excuse my ignorance as i am still learning this framework.

Comment: @MarcusH But I don't think he will be writing his markup in the head section.

Comment: @Redmoomba don't be sorry. That is how you learn. But the answer is you have to include the file in index.html. Because when angular finds the ng-view tag, it either looks in html that you have used the ng-controller tag or it looks in route config that either you have mentioned a controller name there or not. If it finds a name, it now looks for the definition of the controller to inject it into app. Here your app is failing because angular is not finding the file thus unable to inject the controller.

Comment: When i read add the controller i was thinking of ng-controller="mainController" vs the script reference to the controller file. i have it working now. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer and upvote it so everyone else gets help from here